# SSH forwarding - x server display remote program on local machine

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, x11forwarding, xserver

Two debian machines

`Debian 10`
`Kali Linux 2020 rolling`

```
lak:~# sudo ssh -XC spusr@192.168.4.2
```

works to forward specific programs like firefox, nautilus

connected via ethernet `lan`

Things noticed

- `Nautilus` works with only a slight lag compared to `local desktop` x display of nautilus,
- `Firefox` lags so user can not enter settings, unsuably slow response, hangs on `X ing` out of browser window.
- `GNUcash` works perfectly - no lag no problems closing or 'X-ing' out
- using the `ssh -C` switch for compression but that does not help.
- two network cards on both machines so both machines can apt-get update while also connected by ssh on separate eth0 card.  so both machines have tested internet connection

Any suggestions to make programs like firefox usable through `ssh forwarding`?

Comment: Have you tried without compression (`-C`)?

Comment: interesting idea....it actually does improve lag a little ...but "firefox not responding" still pops up before firefox "close 2 tabs" confirmation.  so there is still a signifigant lag but less lag than with - C.  If lag could be reduced by one more step it would be usable.....